# Express $\cos10 x$ in terms of $\sin x$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have to solve the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos10x}$ and I thought of expressing $\cos10x$ in terms of $\cos x$, but I'm also wondering if it can be done in a simpler way that doesn't involve derivatives (not that my way does) or anything like that, just trigonometric knowledge, algebraic manipulation and, of course, basic calculus.

Comment: Why does your title say $\sin x$ where your question says $\cos x?$

Comment: In the end. this limit is really about the first and second derivative of $f(t)=\cos t$ at $t=0$ You can prove it without using the derivatives of $\cos(t),$ but you are essentially reproducing the first steps of proving the derivative results.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:- Are you familiar with the fact thar for a continuous function $f$ such that $f(a)=b$ then $$\lim_{x\to b} g(x)= \lim_{y\to a} g(f(y))$$.

Then what can you say about the transformation $x\mapsto 10x$?

Doesn't the limit become:- $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{100}\frac{(10x)^{2}}{1-\cos(10x)}=\frac{1}{100}\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y^{2}}{1-\cos(y)}$$.

Now can you do it using trig identities?

Answer (score 0):

We know that :
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{1-\cos u}{u^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
Then, we write :
$$\frac{x^2}{1-\cos (10x)} = \frac{1}{100}\frac{(10x)^2}{1-\cos(10x)}$$
Since $\lim_{x\to 0} 10x = 0$, composition of limits gives us :
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos(10x)} = \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{1}{100} \frac{u^2}{1-\cos(u)} = \frac{1}{50}$$